# Adding a variable to a vector in c++

Tags: c++, variables, vector

I have a `std::vector` called `possible_numbers` and I am trying to use its `.push_back()` method to add the value of the variable `i` to the back of the vector. When I try to do it, my code ends up adding `i` to the vector, instead of the value of `i`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> possible_numbers;
    for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        possible_numbers.push_back("i");
    }
}
```

I think that it might be the quotation marks around `i`. However, when I try removing them, I get quite a long error from my compiler written below:

```
guess_number.cpp: In function 'int main()':
guess_number.cpp:7:33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(int&)'
    7 |     possible_numbers.push_back(i);
      |                                 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\vector:67,
                 from guess_number.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1184:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
 1184 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
PS (my file's directory)> g++ guess_number.cpp
PS (My file's directory> g++ guess_number.cpp
guess_number.cpp: In function 'int main()':
guess_number.cpp:7:33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(int&)'
    7 |     possible_numbers.push_back(i);
      |                                 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\vector:67,
                 from guess_number.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1184:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
 1184 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1184:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'const value_type&' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'}
 1184 |       push_back(const value_type& __x)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1200:7: note: candidate: 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'       
 1200 |       push_back(value_type&& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1200:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value_type&&' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&&'}
 1200 |       push_back(value_type&& __x)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: If the vector is supposed to hold numbers, why is it a vector of `std::string`s and not a vector of `int`s?

Comment: Honestly, the whole 4-space thing for code is dumb. I exclusively use the triple back-tick method, and I believe SO is going to eventually go exclusively that route as well, but until then, I get why more than a couple lines of code is a major pain, as the 4-space method is still the first one recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code snippet:

1. If you are trying to generate a list of numbers, why are you using `std::vector<std::string>`? This is creating a vector of strings, if you are looking for ints, use `std::vector<int>`.
2. Pushing `"i"` is pushing the string literal `"i"`, not the variable `i`. When removing the `"`s, you are pushing an `int` into a vector expecting `string`, that's why you get an error for no overload for a `push_back()` with argument `int` for a vector of strings. Another one of the errors is the compiler failing to convert `"i"` from `char` to `int`.

What you are likely looking for is:

```
int main() {
   std::vector<int> possible_numbers;
   for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
      possible_numbers.push_back(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my second time working with vectors so I did not know that you could create a int vector. Though the code you stated won't work when I run it. It gives me a error message saying this: guess_number.cpp:7:24: error: request for member 'push_back' in 'possible_numbers', which is of non-class type 'int'. Do you know what I could use instead of push back? Thank you

Comment: @Dragon_31 that error message is saying that `possible_numbers` is declared as an `int`, but you want it to be a `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @Austin I ran your code again now that you edited it, and it worked now that is says "int" instead of "std::int". Thanks. I had spent a lot of time trying to fix my code and I couldn't fix the problem until you wrote that code :)

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue is your vector called `possible_numbers` is holding `std::string` instead of a numerical type. Judging by your code, you intend for it to hold `int`s in the range [1, 100].

With your code, it's as simple as replacing `<std::string>` with `<int>` in your declaration of `possible_numbers` and removing the quotes around `i` in your call to `push_back()`.

But with natural numbers in sequence, there's a simpler method using [`std::iota()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) from `<numeric>`:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v(100);

  std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

  for (auto i : v) {
    std::cout << std::setw(3) << i << (i % 20 == 0 ? '\n' : ' ');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60
 61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
 81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```